# Producer Consumer Blocking Queue

Tags: java, queue, blocking

I have a situation where I have multiple producers and single consumer.
For performance reasons I don't want consumer to be in any kind of blocking, but since there can be more producers they should be "blocking" if queue full.

Is there any queue offering me such behavior or how can I modify ArrayBlockingQueue  for my needs?

Comment: `ArrayBlockingQueue` is not final, you can extends and override the its functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Use non-blocking `ArrayBlockingQueue.poll` for the consumer and blocking `ArrayBlockingQueue.put` for the producers

Comment: I may not understand this correctly or I expressed my self badly, but looking at the source code for ArrayBlockingQeueu, poll is still acquiring a lock, which means that if there are other locks it will be queued to get its turn... no? I don't want consumer to be anyhow involved in the locking - just grab from the given index and notify producers. I already have this implementation with poll, but looks like consumer is somehow "starving" because pool of producers (equals to queue length) are competing and waiting (holding locks I assume).

Comment: Well you said you dont want blocking and poll never blocks. As for locking, I am afraid you cannot make a lock-free BlockingQueue because it needs to wait / notify somehow

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with any of the `BlockingQueue` implementations?  Your consumer can call <strike>`peek()`</strike>  `poll()` which is non-blocking and your producers can call `put(E e)` which blocks if the queue is full.

**UPDATE**

If the queue is being used for an incredibly intensive task, then [LMAX's disruptor ring buffer](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) is likely to be the most performant queueing structure.

Comment: I need to revise how this locking works. I may not understand the concept correctly. If there is lock acquired by producer and it enters "await" state... then consumer wants to get some element and also performs "lock" on the queue - what happenes? doesn't producer hold a lock?

Comment: There is a (small) possibility that the consumer thread could get context switched out during the call to `poll()` and whilst holding the lock, blocking the other consumers, but this would likely be short-lived.  Unless you're under *significant* (in the order of hundreds of thousands of queue accesses per second) then I would not expect it to cause you problems.  If you *are* doing something that intensive, then take a look at LMAX's disruptor: http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/